# border-color does not change on focus

Tags: html, css

[image]

```css
.form-field {
  position: relative;
  width: 370px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-left: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.label {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 42px;
  margin-top: 12px;
  width: 58px;
  height: 16px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 16px;
  letter-spacing: 0.01em;
  color: #757575;
}
.connection-field {
  padding-left: 42px;
  width: 370px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(33, 33, 33, 0.2);
}
 .connection-field:focus {
   color: #2196f3;
   border-color: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-field">
<label class="label" for="user_name">Имя</label>
<input class="connection-field" type="text" name="Имя"id="user_name">
<svg class="modal-icon-1">
<use xlink:href="#modal-icon-1"></use>
</svg>
</input>
</div>
```

The color of the input frame does not change when: focus ... border-color - does not change ... here I am writing something - because you see my code is not enough and you need to come up

Comment: `@максим` I have added a solution, please have a look.

Answer (score 1):

add `outline:none;` and `border` for on focus. It will be works.

```css
.form-field {
  position: relative;
  width: 370px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-left: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.label {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 42px;
  margin-top: 12px;
  width: 58px;
  height: 16px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 16px;
  letter-spacing: 0.01em;
  color: #757575;
}
.connection-field {
  padding-left: 42px;
  width: 370px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(33, 33, 33, 0.2);
}
 .connection-field:focus {
   outline: none !important;
   color: #2196f3;
   border:1px solid red;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #f00; /*--optional--*/
}
```

```html
<div class="form-field">
<label class="label" for="user_name">Имя</label>
<input class="connection-field" type="text" name="Имя"id="user_name">
<svg class="modal-icon-1">
<use xlink:href="#modal-icon-1"></use>
</svg>
</input>
</div>
```

Please try to post your question in English not any other language.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the working solution:

```
 .connection-field:focus {
   outline: none;
   color: #2196f3;
   border:1px solid red;
}
```

[Please check this CodePen link](https://codepen.io/rashedrahat/pen/jOyNMzx)

Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

--Just add outline: none and you're write border not border-color or write border-color: red  .

```
              .form-field {
                position: relative;
                width: 370px;
                height: 40px;
                margin-left: 40px;
                margin-bottom: 30px;
            }
            .label {
                position: absolute;
                margin-left: 42px;
                margin-top: 12px;
                width: 58px;
                height: 16px;
                font-size: 14px;
                line-height: 16px;
                letter-spacing: 0.01em;
                color: #757575;
            }
            .connection-field {
                padding-left: 42px;
                width: 370px;
                height: 40px;
                border-radius: 4px;
                border: 1px solid rgba(33, 33, 33, 0.2);
                outline: none; /*here add outline: none*/
                
            }
            .connection-field:focus {
                color: #2196f3;
                border: 1px solid red; /* here write border not border-color */
            }
```